# Facebook auto wall post, "only me" issue

Tags: share, facebook-wall

I'm trying to make an app which asks users permissions and auto posts to his wall as himself. It works but there is an issue. That post can see only himself: "Shared with: Only me"
How can i make, that it would be: "Shared with: Public"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default setting for each user is user's default setting

if you have same problem with other users  check here & Default Activity Privacy
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/auth

Comment: i installed your app & post shared in my default privacy(public)

Comment: it is interesting, because i created new FB user and his default privacy settings on this app is "Shared with: Only me"... :|

Comment: recommend: dont make new users 
use test users for your app

Comment: i installed your app with my second profile & there was no problem again the post  posted in public (my privacy is in friends)